# How to use XSLT 1.0 or XQuery 1.0 to simulate sql (group by and working with multiple xml nodes)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xquery, xslt-grouping

I have 4 xml documents in nodes and I am trying to use XSLT 1.0 or XQuery 1.0 to process query these xml files and generate one xml as output. I am not sure how to use key and group-by functionality in XSLT 1.0 and how to efficiently query multiple xml nodes to form one output xml. (there are multiple rows in each xml file)

tableA

```
   <table>
    <row>
     <id></id>
     <group></group>
     <version></version>
     <status></status>
    <row>
   <table>
```

tableB

```
   <table>
    <row>
     <id></id>
     <group></group>
     <version></version>
    </row>
   <table>
```

tableC

```
   <table>
    <row>
     <id></id>
     <code></code>
     <version></version>
     <code_version></code_version>
     <version></version>
    </row>
   <table>
```

tableD

```
   <table>
    <row>
     <id></id>
     <code></code>
     <code_version></code_version>
     <date></date>
    </row>
   <table>
```

My SQL Query:

```
  SELECT a.[id]
  ,c.[code]
  ,d.[date]
  ,a.[group ]
  FROM [source].[dbo].[tableA] a, [source].[dbo].[tableB] b, 
  [source].[dbo].[tableC] c, [source].[dbo].[tableD] d

 WHERE a.[id] = b.[id] 
  AND a.[version] = b.[version] 
  AND a.[id] = c.[id] 
  AND a.[version] = c.[version]
  AND c.[code] = d.[code] 
  AND c.[code_version] = d.[code_version]
  GROUP BY a.[id]
  ,c.[code]
  ,d.[date]
  ,a.[status]
  ORDER BY  a.[id], c.[code]
```

I also tried creating partial XQuery 1.0, but it is not working.

My XQuery 1.0:

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace ms = "http://www.ms.com/extensions";

let $A := fn:doc('tableA.xml')
let $B := fn:doc('tableB.xml')
let $C := fn:doc('tableC.xml')
let $D := fn:doc('tableD.xml')

for $a in $A,
    $b in $B,
    $c in $C,
    $d in $D

where $a/table/row/id = $b/table/row/id 
and $a/table/row/version = $b/table/row/version 
and $a/table/row/id = $c/table/row/id 
and $a/table/row/version = $c/table/row/version 
and $c/table/row/code = $d/table/row/code
and $c/table/row/code_version = $d/table/row/code_version

order by $a
return $a
```

This is just a partial query. This query works good if i don't apply where clause on $c and $d. I am not sure if this is the right way to perform this operation though.

Comment: With XSLT 1.0, the usual Muenchian grouping approach uses a key and is therefore restricted to a single document, so you would need to build `<xsl:variable name="union-rtf"><table><xsl:copy-of select="document('a.xml)/table/* | document('b.xml')/table/* | document('c.xml')/table/* | document('d.xml')/table/*"/></table></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="union-doc" select="exsl:node-set($union-rtf)"/>` and then set up a key or the keys (not sure how the SQL translates, can you show the result you want?).

Comment: @Martin Honnen The ouput would look something like this:                                           <table>
 <row>
  <id></id>
  <code></code>
  <date></date>
  <group></group>
 <row>
 <row>
  <id></id>
  <code></code>
  <date></date>
  <group></group>
 <row>
</table>                                                                                                                The problem is that some column are common between these xml, so I am not sure how will i make one of the column as key.